# Conditionally adding element to list var in ansible-playbook

Tags: ansible

I am using ansible 2.13 on elementary-os hera (essentially ubuntu 18.04). I have an ansible-playbook yml with essentially the following content:

```
- hosts: db
  roles:
    - monitoring
    - db
    - ssh_keys
```

Accompanying the playbook is a large set of dependency files that I am not familiar with. I am trying to modify the playbook such that based on the value of a boolean var (let's call it myBoolVar) set elsewhere, I can add one more the list of roles (let's call it myRole).

Some of the solutions I found online suggested I should use set_fact, but I get this error back:

```
ERROR! 'set_fact' is not a valid attribute for a Play
```

I saw some solutions suggesting using 'when' but when I tried I got back an error similar to the above.

I tried using the solution in this post:
[Add an item to a list dependent on a conditional in ansible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39165463/add-an-item-to-a-list-dependent-on-a-conditional-in-ansible)

However the error I got back was unhelpful:

```
    ERROR! A malformed role declaration was encountered.

The error appears to be in '....yml': line 29, column 3, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:


- hosts: db
  ^ here
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create [role](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_reuse_roles.html#using-roles-at-the-play-level) dictionaries to pass [keywords](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/playbooks_keywords.html#role). For example,

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: all
  roles:
    - role: monitoring
    - role: db
    - role: ssh_keys
    - role: myRole
      when: myBoolVar|d(false)|bool
```

Given the below task is common to all roles

```yaml
shell> cat roles/*/tasks/main.yml 
- debug:
    msg: "Role {{ ansible_role_name }} running ..."
```

the play gives (abridged)

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml -l test_11
  ...
  msg: Role monitoring running ...
  msg: Role db running ...
  msg: Role ssh_keys running ...
  ...
TASK [myRole : debug] *********************************************************
skipping: [test_11]
```

Enable your role

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml -l test_11 -e myBoolVar=true
  ...
  msg: Role monitoring running ...
  msg: Role db running ...
  msg: Role ssh_keys running ...
  msg: Role myRole running ...
  ...
```

Notes:

- You have to explicitly convert the [extra variable](https://docs.ansible.com/archive/ansible/2.6/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#passing-variables-on-the-command-line) to [bool](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_filters.html#forcing-the-data-type) because the ini format recognizes strings only.
- Disable displaying skipped tasks

```bash
shell> ANSIBLE_DISPLAY_SKIPPED_HOSTS=false ansible-playbook pb.yml ...
```

- See other options for a callback. By default,

```bash
shell> ansible-doc -t callback default
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, Vladimir. I'll try this and reply shortly. And I'll mark the answer as Accepted if it works for me. Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: Thanks again to Vladimir! This worked. One difference in what I did was to use myBoolVar|bool instead of this myBoolVar|d(false)|bool because the default value was being set to false elsewhere.